# How can we search and find the `Array number` of a property name `schools` matched with some `search text`

Tags: javascript

How can we search and find the `Array number` of a property name `schools` matched with some `search text` in a complex Json array as given below: I have tried the below code, but it is not working.

```
const searchText = "South School";
var myArr = [];
myArr = response.body.schools;

 var results = myArr.filter(function(myArr) {
   return myArr.schools.indexOf(searchText) > -1;
 });
```

Based on the above search text, I would need to find the `array number matching to the search text` from the below json. When I observered the chrome console, I could see the following array range .

[image]

```
{  
   "lastUpdated":"2019-08-27T00:07:58.7222559+00:00",
   "alerts":[  
      {  
         "id":"ea229500-bc49-4dda",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"b04fc2fb-3e62-4b4e",
               "name":"North School-Upper",
               "region":"North Island",
               "station":"125001",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7304497+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"https://testurl.com"
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-25T03:47:26.0493451+00:00",
         "title":"North School",
         "subTitle":"Forecast results",
         "description":"North School",
         "status":1,
         "statusDescription":"Draft",
         "scheduledFor":"2019-08-28T03:30:00+00:00",
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":false,
         "isEmailNotification":false,
         "facebookPost":null,
         "twitterPost":"First twitter post of school"
      },
      {  
         "id":"a4d78fdf-bcca-4304",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"e8b45981-53aa-4061",
               "name":"South School",
               "region":"Far South School",
               "station":"110A",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7305428+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"http://testurl
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:01:33.4345038+00:00",
         "title":"Some new ideas",
         "subTitle":"A blueberry sees an orange.",
         "description":"Unfortunately, that is wrong; on the contrary, some skillful snakes",
         "status":3,
         "statusDescription":"Sent",
         "imageUrl":null,
         "scheduledFor":null,
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":true,
         "isEmailNotification":true,
         "facebookPost":"Facebook post inserted while updating\n",
         "twitterPost":"Twitter post inserted while creating\n"
      },....
      // JSOn data continues here

      ]

}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to match the searchText with which key from the response?

Comment: The data you have shared and log screenshot does not match. Can you please share proper data?

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
var results = myArr.filter(function(myArrElement) {
   return myArrElement.schools.name.indexOf(searchText) > -1;
 });
```

```js
//Considering with sample data
let dams = [
 {  
         "id":"a4d78fdf-bcca-4304",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"e8b45981-53aa-4061",
               "name":"South School",
               "region":"Far South School",
               "station":"110A",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7305428+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"http://testurl"
            }
         ],
    }
];

var results = function(){
    let newArray = [];
    dams.forEach(function(damElement) {
        damElement.schools.forEach((item,index) => {if(item.name == "South School") newArray.push(damElement);});
    });
 return newArray;
};

console.log(results());
```

Comment: It is throwing  TypeError: Cannot read property 'schools' of undefined

Comment: Can you share the actual content of myArr?

Comment: It has got some project details, so I have changed some property name to `schools` from actual one

Comment: Updated one screen shot for reference...instead of `schools` it is dams.

Comment: Its printing now  `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...`

Comment: I am running your code now and the console.log(results()); is printing as above...

Answer (score 1):

According to your sample data, you will need to filter three times.

```js
var searchText = "South School";
var schools = [];
var arr = [
    {  
   "lastUpdated":"2019-08-27T00:07:58.7222559+00:00",
   "alerts":[  
      {  
         "id":"ea229500-bc49-4dda",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"b04fc2fb-3e62-4b4e",
               "name":"North School-Upper",
               "region":"North Island",
               "station":"125001",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7304497+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"https://testurl.com"
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-25T03:47:26.0493451+00:00",
         "title":"North School",
         "subTitle":"Forecast results",
         "description":"North School",
         "status":1,
         "statusDescription":"Draft",
         "scheduledFor":"2019-08-28T03:30:00+00:00",
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":false,
         "isEmailNotification":false,
         "facebookPost":null,
         "twitterPost":"First twitter post of school"
      },
      {  
         "id":"a4d78fdf-bcca-4304",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"e8b45981-53aa-4061",
               "name":"South School",
               "region":"Far South School",
               "station":"110A",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7305428+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"http://testurl"
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:01:33.4345038+00:00",
         "title":"Some new ideas",
         "subTitle":"A blueberry sees an orange.",
         "description":"Unfortunately, that is wrong; on the contrary, some skillful snakes",
         "status":3,
         "statusDescription":"Sent",
         "imageUrl":null,
         "scheduledFor":null,
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":true,
         "isEmailNotification":true,
         "facebookPost":"Facebook post inserted while updating\n",
         "twitterPost":"Twitter post inserted while creating\n"
      }
   ]

},
{  
   "lastUpdated":"2019-08-27T00:07:58.7222559+00:00",
   "alerts":[  
      {  
         "id":"ea229500-bc49-4dda",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"b04fc2fb-3e62-4b4e",
               "name":"North School-Upper",
               "region":"North Island",
               "station":"125001",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7304497+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"https://testurl.com"
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-25T03:47:26.0493451+00:00",
         "title":"North School",
         "subTitle":"Forecast results",
         "description":"North School",
         "status":1,
         "statusDescription":"Draft",
         "scheduledFor":"2019-08-28T03:30:00+00:00",
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":false,
         "isEmailNotification":false,
         "facebookPost":null,
         "twitterPost":"First twitter post of school"
      },
      {  
         "id":"a4d78fdf-bcca-4304",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"e8b45981-53aa-4061",
               "name":"South School",
               "region":"Far South School",
               "station":"110A",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7305428+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"http://testurl"
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:01:33.4345038+00:00",
         "title":"Some new ideas",
         "subTitle":"A blueberry sees an orange.",
         "description":"Unfortunately, that is wrong; on the contrary, some skillful snakes",
         "status":3,
         "statusDescription":"Sent",
         "imageUrl":null,
         "scheduledFor":null,
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":true,
         "isEmailNotification":true,
         "facebookPost":"Facebook post inserted while updating\n",
         "twitterPost":"Twitter post inserted while creating\n"
      }
   ]

},
{  
   "lastUpdated":"2019-08-27T00:07:58.7222559+00:00",
   "alerts":[  
      {  
         "id":"ea229500-bc49-4dda",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"b04fc2fb-3e62-4b4e",
               "name":"North School-Upper",
               "region":"North Island",
               "station":"125001",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7304497+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"https://testurl.com"
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-25T03:47:26.0493451+00:00",
         "title":"North School",
         "subTitle":"Forecast results",
         "description":"North School",
         "status":1,
         "statusDescription":"Draft",
         "scheduledFor":"2019-08-28T03:30:00+00:00",
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":false,
         "isEmailNotification":false,
         "facebookPost":null,
         "twitterPost":"First twitter post of school"
      },
      {  
         "id":"a4d78fdf-bcca-4304",
         "schools":[  
            {  
               "id":"e8b45981-53aa-4061",
               "name":"South School",
               "region":"Far north School",
               "station":"110A",
               "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:00:11.7305428+00:00",
               "percentageFull":0.00,
               "winStorageUrl":"http://testurl"
            }
         ],
         "lastUpdate":"2019-08-27T00:01:33.4345038+00:00",
         "title":"Some new ideas",
         "subTitle":"A blueberry sees an orange.",
         "description":"Unfortunately, that is wrong; on the contrary, some skillful snakes",
         "status":3,
         "statusDescription":"Sent",
         "imageUrl":null,
         "scheduledFor":null,
         "deletedDate":null,
         "isInApp":true,
         "isEmailNotification":true,
         "facebookPost":"Facebook post inserted while updating\n",
         "twitterPost":"Twitter post inserted while creating\n"
      }
   ]

}
];

arr.filter(each => {
    each.alerts.filter(alert => {
        alert.schools.filter(school => {
            if (school.name.indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
                schools.push(school.name);
            }
        });
    });
});
console.log(schools);
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: `filter` only works on Array type. My example code works because every time `filter` has been fired on an array. Because I don't know your exact object structure so please make sure every time when you call `filter` on a variable, it's an array.